# Request login and data pull

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to use Python and Request to login to a website but can't seem to get it to work. I'm pretty new to Python but it appears request is pretty simple to use.

I can successfully iniate a session and get the HTML data, but can't figure out why post is not successfully loging me in.

My code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url="https://www.trilink-usa-portal.com/cs/index.php"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())


 payload = {
    'usercode' : '{username}',
    'password' : '{password}',
    'login' : 'Login',
    'sid':'{sid}',
    'redirect' : '{redirect}'
 }

with requests.Session() as s:


    s.get(url)
    p = s.post("https://www.trilink-usa-portal.com/cs/index.php?login", data=payload)

    print(p.text)

    r = s.get("https://www.trilink-usa-portal.com/cs/rpt01V2.php")
    print(r.text)
```

I'm not sure if I need the sid or redirect, but any help would be appreciated. My print of 'r' just shows the html of the login page.

Comment: Try `payload = {'usercode':user, 'password':pwd, 'Submit':'Login', 'action':'login'}`

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any chance you could help with another site? This one uses JavaScript. link is `(https://www.emlco.com/control/formbasedloginscreen)`

Comment: Yes, try `payload = {'j_username':user, 'j_password':pwd, 'x':'0', 'y':'0'}` You can get the fieldnames if you inspect the html or network traffic.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, that doesn't seem to log me in. Unless I'm running the other code wrong. I'm using `.get()` to pull the login page, `.post('link', payload)` to push the login, then using a second `.get()` command to pull the data from the correct page. All this is done within a session. Also, where did you get the 'x' and 'y' from. I didn't see them in the inspector?

Comment: I managed to get it. The login had a redirect that I was missing. Thanks again.